# Moodle Login with facebook

Tags: redirect, authentication, oauth-2.0, moodle

Using Oauth2 plugin for Moodle, users get redirected to my index page when logging in with Facebook. How to direct them to the navigation dashboard instead?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to take a look at checking your redirect uri options in Oauth-[Forming the URL for an authentication request](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#formingtheurl)

If that doesn't do it simply navigating to your Moodle to here `admin/settings.php?section=manageauths` and search for the field '*Alternate login URL*' and specify your dashboard link should do the trick.